# Create user without adding subuid range

Tags: useradd

Is it possible to create a new user e.g. with `useradd` without adding an entry to `/etc/subuid` even if the latter file exists?

I use `/etc/subuid` only to for the user namespacing by Docker but don't want all other manually users manually to get subuid ranges assigned.

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: It would help if you gave more information about what you are trying to accomplish (more generally). There may be ways of doing what you want other than not adding manually-configured users to `/etc/subuid`.

Comment: It's right there: "user namespacing by Docker", see [the docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). I don't use the namespacing for anything else. However, from further reading the man pages, I  came to the conclusion that it's either "remove unneeded lines in subuid/subgid manually" or removing the owner write permission from it, which seems to intrusive for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by setting SUB_UID_COUNT to 0 in /etc/login.defs.